# jQuery Accordion know when panel finished opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using `jQuery Accordion` and need to know when a panel has finished loading. I understand that I need to bind the `accordionchange` event, but I am really confused from there how I will know when a panel has opened.

If I just put an `alert()` inside the function it DOES show after the panel has opened, but it also shows after the panel is closed:

```
$("#campaigns").accordion({ 
    event: 'click',
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
}).bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
    alert('Panel opened and closed');
});
```

**How can I only know when the panel has finished opening?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working how I wanted. Here is how I know when opening a panel:

```
$("#campaigns").accordion({ 
    event: 'click',
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    change: function(event, ui) {

        // See if we are opening a panel
        var allOpen = ui.oldHeader.length == 1 && ui.newHeader.length == 1 && ui.oldContent.length == 1 && ui.newContent.length == 1;
        var newOpen = ui.newHeader.length == 1 && ui.newContent.length == 1;
        if (allOpen || newOpen) {

            // Do something here each time the panel is opened

        }//end if

    }//end change
});
```

Strangely, `change` seems to not be documented...

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate - look at the event - it is triggered when a panel is activated (opened).

Comment: I tried that but it does not seem to call the function or alert at all.